# Open all files in Sublime Text from a directory except ones explicitly specified

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, sublimetext

I know that we can use this command `find . -type f ! -name '[PATTERN]'` to find all files in the current directory except the ones that match the specified search pattern, but what do I do to feed the files so found as command-line arguments into the Sublime Text editor to open them up in there?

```
misha@hp-laptop:~/work/cpp/class$ ls -l
total 28
-rwxrwxr-x 1 misha misha 14252 Mar 24 00:49 out
-rw-rw-r-- 1 misha misha   236 Mar 24 00:48 Person.cpp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 misha misha   255 Mar 24 00:49 Person.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 misha misha   200 Mar 24 00:49 test.cpp
misha@hp-laptop:~/work/cpp/class$ find . -type f ! -name 'out'
./Person.h
./test.cpp
./Person.cpp
misha@hp-laptop:~/work/cpp/class$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, [`xargs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) is your friend!  It allows you to turn lines from STDIN into parameters.

Assuming you can open files with `sublime some_file some_other_file ...`, you can use:

```
find . -type f ! -name 'out' | xargs sublime
```

In your case, it will take the output from `find`

```
./Person.h
./test.cpp
./Person.cpp
```

And append them to `sublime` to build and run a command:

```
sublime ./Person.h ./test.cpp ./Person.cpp
```